# How does Smalltalk handle program error?

Tags: smalltalk, error-handling

I'm a newbie on Smalltalk. I have read some articles and documents about it and I am surprised about its completeness of concepts. And it offers some kind of live debugging.

Anyway, for program errors, the error means the program logic is wrong, and all accumulated mutations by the program are all invalid. To guarantee integrity, the whole program should be restarted from some point, and the whole program state should be rollback.

How does Smalltalk handle this? (maybe this question can be applied to all dynamic REPL languages...)

Answer (score 6):

Smalltalk uses Exception objects. I recommend you to read the chapter about that https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/26600/PBE2-Exceptions-2010-03-02.pdf

it is part of the Pharo By Example book: http://pharobyexample.org/

Regarding the mutation, debugging, etc, note that Smalltalk reifies lot of stuff in the language. For example, the MethodContext class. Those objects reprents the method contexts that the VM is executing. So you can inspect them, and play with them just as a regular objects. The same with CompiledMethod. Just for fun, inspect the "pseudo" variable 'thisContext' :)

IF you want to answer your answers yourself, take a look to the Debugger class. So, do you want to know what happens when you restart the method in the middle of the debugger? then browse the method #restart in Debugger and follow :)

Answer (score 3):

You're asking, in effect, "how can this *entire computer* roll back to a known state?", because a Smalltalk image is a virtual machine in same sense that VMWare and VirtualBox are.

The closest that we have to the ability to undo arbitrary side effects (excluding obvious impossibilities like rolling back I/O) is probably Alessandro Warth's *Worlds*, as described in his PhD thesis [Experimenting with Programming Languages](http://www.vpri.org/pdf/tr2008003_experimenting.pdf). At least in a generic sense: it's of course possible to use things like the Memento and Command patterns to implement undoable operations.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to a lot of objects in the image that can get into inconsistent state while developing and debugging. Usual procedure is to store code in packages like (Monticello for squeak/pharo). When you want to *reset* things, you would get a clean image from the distribution and reload code from the packages. For deployed applications in addition to code in the packages, you would usually have information needed to recreate your data objects stored in some external form like serialized form stored in the files, or in dql or noSql database. So your reset procedure would be take fresh image, load code from the packages, load your data model objects from external store.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't!

From the smalltalks I know none of them supports this kind of transaction. All side effects that are accumulated during execution are set. There is no supported automatic rollback. There is research undergoing how to support this but nothing to try out AFAIK. It is something you have to know that if you are debugging and you go back in the stack trace that the objects aren't in the state they were at execution time. You see just the objects in their newest state.

While it is not that easy to support this in a generic fashion there are some possibilities to solve this with the design of your program. The most prominent approaches are:

- you copy/clone the objects you want to modify and apply the changes to the copies. If something goes wrong you just throw away the copies. If everything is fine you apply the content of the copies to the originals. You can solve this using the memento pattern.
- you apply changes to your objects but if something goes wrong you re-apply the original content. That can be implemented with do/undo actions using the command pattern